# Incorrect value for str_to_date

Tags: mysql, date-format

I'm running a simple procedure that reads from a `VARCHAR` column and inserts data into a `TIME` column, using this format:

```
STR_TO_DATE(vTestTime, '%H:%i').
```

I'm getting the error

> SQL Error (1411): Incorrect datetime value: '09:22' for function str_to_date

I find that a similar statement, `SELECT STR_TO_DATE("09:22", "%H:%i")` gives me a NULL when I run it from a HeidiSQL client.

I'm sure this syntax used to work and I'm not aware of having changed any settings, can you suggest what I've done wrong?

Edit: Just remembered I have made a recent change, I installed a Wordpress database on the same server, might that have had some affect?

Here's what get running on the server:

```
mysql> select str_to_date("09:22", "%H:%i");

+-------------------------------+

| str_to_date("09:22", "%H:%i") |

+-------------------------------+

| NULL                          |

+-------------------------------+

1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Warning (Code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: '09:22' for function str_to_date
```

Comment: It should work: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=3ebb9e0fb893866663c9463a7fb94ca8

Comment: See if you have `ANSI_QUOTES` enabled.

Comment: No, `ANSI_QUOTES` is not enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug (though it isn't technically a bug, see my first edit towards the end of the answer):

I see the behaviour on MySQL 5.7.20 and 5.7.21 (on Centos 7.4 if it matters):

```
mysql> select str_to_date("09:22", "%H:%i");
+-------------------------------+
| str_to_date("09:22", "%H:%i") |
+-------------------------------+
| NULL                          |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

And the warning is code 1411 `Incorrect datetime value: '09:22' for function str_to_date`.

ANSI_QUOTES is not enabled, and I get the same warning if I use single-quotes.

From what I understand reading [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), the query should work:

> STR_TO_DATE() returns a DATETIME value if the format string contains
>   both date and time parts, or a DATE or TIME value if the string
>   contains only date or time parts.

This query, containing a date as well as a time part, does work:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE("2017-03-17 09:22","%Y-%m-%d %H:%i");
+--------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE("2017-03-17 09:22","%Y-%m-%d %H:%i") |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| 2017-03-17 09:22:00                              |
+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Running the original query on MariaDB 10.2.14 works correctly:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select str_to_date("09:22", "%H:%i");
+-------------------------------+
| str_to_date("09:22", "%H:%i") |
+-------------------------------+
| 09:22:00                      |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT:**
This was reported as a bug previously, see here:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80064

> If the NO_ZERO_DATE or NO_ZERO_IN_DATE SQL mode is enabled, zero dates
>   or part of dates are disallowed. In that case, STR_TO_DATE() returns
>   NULL and generates a warning:

These modes are enabled by default in MySQL 5.7 (but not in MariaDB 10.2). So, after removing these from the sql_mode system variable, we get the desired result:

```
mysql> SET sql_mode='';
mysql> select STR_TO_DATE("09:22", "%H:%i");
+-------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE("09:22", "%H:%i") |
+-------------------------------+
| 09:22:00                      |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT 2:**
We don't want to accidentally remove helpful/important modes from the `sql_mode` system variable, so ideally we should only remove specific modes, in this case NO_ZERO_DATE and NO_ZERO_IN_DATE. This can be done this way:

```
SET @@SQL_MODE = REPLACE(@@SQL_MODE, 'NO_ZERO_DATE', '');
SET @@SQL_MODE = REPLACE(@@SQL_MODE, 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE', '');
```

(Use `SET GLOBAL sql_mode...` if you want to change it for the global scope rather than just the session.)

If you want to set `sql_mode` in the MySQL config file, then I think you'll just have to "hard-code" it, i.e. just find out what the default modes are for the version you're using, remove the undesired modes, and add the resulting string e.g. to the `[mysqld]` section of the .cnf file:

```
sql-mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

This should be correct for MySQL 5.7. When upgrading to the next version, you'll have to update the setting again.

Note that stored procedures run with their own `sql_mode`s:

> MySQL stores the sql_mode system variable setting in effect when a
>   routine is created or altered, and always executes the routine with
>   this setting in force, regardless of the current server SQL mode when
>   the routine begins executing.

Source: [the MySQL stored procedure documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html).

You can also change the `sql_mode` within a stored procedure.

Comment: @user147997 Glad I could help. Obviously, it's not a good idea to just blank sql_mode like I did. Instead, just the two problematic modes should be removed. I'll update the answer to show this later ...

Comment: Thanks, I'd be interested in the correct way to do this. I added an "sql_mode=..." in the mysql.conf include file and restarted mysql. I found this fixed my interactive test using HeidiSQL and a simple select statement. But it didn't stop the stored procedure failing with the same original error. Finally I got it working by adding an "sql_mode=..." statement in the stored procedure. Not great!

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer. If you set your desired `sql_mode` and then recreate the stored procedure(s) within that session, it should work. Then you don't have the change the `sql_mode` within the SP.

Comment: [merry christmas](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/pull/224). Also [mysql bug 71386](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71386)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to update sql_mode just add todays date infront of time and then it will work.

Problem:

```
mysql> select str_to_date("09:22", "%H:%i");
+-------------------------------+
| str_to_date("09:22", "%H:%i") |
+-------------------------------+
| NULL                          |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Solution:

My table looks like this.

```
mysql> select * from restaurant_delivery_slots;
+----+---------------+-----------+------------+------------------+--------+
| id | restaurant_id | open_time | close_time | delivery_charges | status |
+----+---------------+-----------+------------+------------------+--------+
| 17 |         99997 | 7:00 AM   | 12:00 PM   |           150.00 |      1 |
| 18 |         99997 | 12:00 PM  | 6:00 PM    |           300.00 |      1 |
| 37 |           102 | 7:00 AM   | 12:00 PM   |           100.00 |      1 |
| 38 |           102 | 12:00 PM  | 5:00 PM    |           200.00 |      1 |
+----+---------------+-----------+------------+------------------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

After implementing solution, you will get result like this.

```
mysql> SELECT
    rds.id,
    rds.open_time,
    rds.close_time,
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(),' ', rds.open_time), "%Y-%m-%d %l:%i %p") AS ot,
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(),' ', rds.close_time), "%Y-%m-%d %l:%i %p") AS ct
    FROM restaurant_delivery_slots rds
    WHERE CONCAT(CURDATE(),' ', '10:49:01' ) BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(),' ', rds.open_time), "%Y-%m-%d %l:%i %p") AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(),' ', rds.close_time), "%Y-%m-%d %l:%i %p");
+----+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | open_time | close_time | ot                  | ct                  |
+----+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 17 | 7:00 AM   | 12:00 PM   | 2022-09-06 07:00:00 | 2022-09-06 12:00:00 |
| 37 | 7:00 AM   | 12:00 PM   | 2022-09-06 07:00:00 | 2022-09-06 12:00:00 |
+----+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

For more info you can contact me.