# Error in STR_TO_DATE when referring to column

Tags: mysql, date-format

I'm trying to copy a VARCHAR column into a DATE column with the following:

`UPDATE memberScores SET tempDate = STR_TO_DATE(eventDate,%d-%m-%Y) WHERE scoreID < 68010;`

The error message that I receive is this:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%d-%m-%Y) WHERE scoreID < 68010' at line 1`

The VARCHAR data in the eventDate column is in the format of 1-15-2010

I've tried several variations on this, such as the following:

`` UPDATE `memberScores` SET `tempDate` = STR_TO_DATE(`eventDate`,%d-%m-%Y) WHERE `scoreID` < 68010; ``

`` INSERT INTO `memberScores`.`tempDate` SELECT STR_TO_DATE(`memberScores`.`eventDate`,%d-%m-%Y) WHERE `memberScores`.`scoreID` < 68010; ``

I did find [Incorrect value for str_to_date](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202627/incorrect-value-for-str-to-date) and I initially thought the answer there was relevant because I'm using Alma Linux (similar to Centos) and the STR_TO_DATE function where the time component was zero... but the fix there didn't work.

MySQL version is 8.0 on Alma Linux 8.7.0

Any ideas?

EDIT - Added the exact error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured this out but I'm leaving it here for any other poor souls in the future that might have the same issue.

I had three mistake, all relating to the STR_TO_DATE function's syntax.

First, I hadn't put the format string in quotes; it should have been:

`STR_TO_DATE(eventDate,"$d-%m-%Y")`

Second, I had the month and the day transposed; it should have been:

`STR_TO_DATE(eventDate,"$m-%d-%Y")`

Lastly, all of the days and months were not zero-filled; for example, April was "4" instead of "04". It should have been:

`STR_TO_DATE(eventDate,"$c-%e-%Y")`

After I made those changes, it worked.

I hope that this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Do not use double-quote chars for string literals! This may cause problems. Use single-quote chars only.